# Android SharedPreferences successfully not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm newbie into android and today I wanted to implement some SharedPreferences.

Here's my code: (or [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFVTb.png) if ou like it more)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
// SOME CODE HERE


    // Initialize Shared Preferences
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
            logMsg(sharedPreferences.toString() + "=>" + s + "=>" + sharedPreferences.getString(s, ""));
        }
    });

    final EditText etId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etId);
    final EditText etValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etValue);

    Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // set Data
            logMsg("Id= " + etId.getText().toString() + " Value= " + etValue.getText().toString());
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(etId.getText().toString(), etValue.getText().toString());
            if (sharedPreferences.edit().commit()){
                logMsg("Success");
            }else {
                logMsg("Fail");
            }

            // get Data
            logMsg("Id= '" + etId.getText().toString() + "' Value= " + sharedPreferences.getString(etId.getText().toString(), "No Value"));
        }
    });


//SOME CODE HERE
}
```

The problem is that after pressing *btn_save* log says **Success on `sharedPreferences.edit().commit()`** but after that **I don't retrieve any data with `getString()`** (respectively I retrieve *dafault value* that is in my case *"No Value"*).

Do you have any idea what's wrong?
Is it necessary to unregister *SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener*?

Thanks.

Comment: `successfully not working` sounds like a **nonsense**, to me...

Comment: @Rotwang that's why I asked you guys for answer :)

Comment: By the way there is a thing called debug which tells you exactly what and where your problem is. please first do the debugging and check what exactly is the problem.
hope you don't mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you call `edit()`, you get a new instance of `SharedPreferences.Editor`. You need to do your modifications and `commit()` (or `apply()`) on the same editor instance.

Therefore, save the return value of `edit()` to a variable, and call `putString()` and `commit()` on that.

Comment: *on the same editor instance.* This is key, it's a good idea to make your SharedPreferences instance a singleton to avoid `apply()` not saving prefs. At this point you should be using `PreferenceManager` from the androidx library